# AngularJs ng-animate on Android Browser

Tags: css, angularjs

This doesn't work on Android 4.03: http://www.yearofmoo.com/nganimate-css3/

which uses the awesome animate css3.

However the authors example works fine: http://daneden.me/animate/

Can anyone explain why the ng-animate version doesn't work?

Ken

Comment: The same on my iPad 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-animate is not working in android WebView of Samaung Galaxy S4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569269/ng-animate-is-not-working-in-android-webview-of-samaung-galaxy-s4)